# Visual Studio, Nodes in Projectexplorer for Partialclasses

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it Possible to set Nodes in the Projectexplorer for each Partialclass in Visual Studio?

Example:

*Creating a Class-File in Visual Studio with 2 Classes inside, leads to a node for every class.*

[image: As seen here]

*Creating a Class-File in VS with a Partial class, doesn't result in a new Node for each Partial class.*

[image]

Is it Possible to have somehting like `MurderAllHumans.Constructors` and a `MurderAllHumans.Methods` Node?
I know it is possible to Achieve something simmular with Folders and multiple .cs files, but i am looking for a way to do this in one file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The Class view will only show one entry for each class and as two files with a partial class is still only one class, there will only be one entry.

Generally it is advised to have only one class per file, and I am not sure I understand why you want to declare the same class partially twice in the same file either.

Maybe you could solve part of your wish but making one region for constructors and another for the methods etc. like this:

[image: Example of region use]

This will however not be reflected in the Class View.

Comment: Ja, was all for code readabillity, a puny little idea i had that i solved with #region's